# Can we initialize an array for a structure with a parametrized constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

**We can initialize an array for a structure which has a default constructor, but can we do that with a parametrized constructor?**

```
struct class{
   int room;
   int floor;
   class(){
    room=0;
    floor=0;
  }
};

int main(){
   class c1[5];
}
```

Above code works fine. But, what to do when there is a parameterized constructor?

```
struct class{
  int room;
  int floor;
  class(int r,int f){
    room=r;
    floor=f;
  }
};
```

Comment: You can't have a keyword as a class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list initialization:

```
struct test {
  test(int,int);
};

test c1[] = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6},
};
```

Comment: Can I make it user-input array?